# mouse_event function to click once

Tags: c#, aforge

im using `mouse_event` function to simulate click when ever my video detects a color like blue, the problem is that when it detects blue it starts clicking over and over, i would like to perform single click when it detects the color and stop until the color goes out and comes back.

```
if(blue=detect)
{
mouse.clickright();
}
```

but when it detects it starts clicking again and again

```
void clickright()
{
x = position.x;
y = position.y;


mouse_event(MOUSE_RIGHTDOWN | MOUSE_RIGHTUP, X,Y,0,0);
}
```

the code behind not the exact .. but you guys can understand :P  `clickright()` how can i stop it after one click HELP !!

Answer (score 0):

Because your 'if' is wrong..

```
if(blue==detect)
{
mouse.clickright();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(blue==detect)
{
mouse.clickright();
'then remove handler for clickright for a while then put it back

}
```

the code behind not the exact .. but you can understand :P

Comment: i dont thinks it is using any handler... there is mouse_event();

Comment: then how he capture the mouse events, Messages?

Comment: i have this color detection when blue color comes in front of camera, it makes a blob around it using aforge.net so i codeded something like this
if(objectreck.IsEmpty == false)
{
mouse.clickright();
}
but the problem is it starts clicking with out stoping ! is there any way to stop it !